# Can't use INTO OUTFILE when using PHP Google App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I tried using INTO OUTFILE and wasn't able to then found that Google actually prohibits this when using Google App Engine. I'm trying to export a large amount of data and was hoping to just use csv to organize it. Looking for another suggestion as I'm still learning and trying to search for howto export using MySQL only returns the below options.

Googles FAQ just so everyone can see what they don't allow

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq

```
 Unsupported MySQL statements:
 Sending any of the following types of SQL statements will generate an error with the     
 message "Error 1290: The MySQL server is running with the google option so it cannot   
 execute this statement"

 LOAD DATA INFILE
 SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE
 SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE
 INSTALL PLUGIN ...
 UNINSTALL PLUGIN
 CREATE FUNCTION ... SONAME ...
```

Thanks to the community as always couldn't of gotten this far without you.

Answer (score 0):

Appengine has explicitly always prevented writing to the local filesystem and is documented in "PHP Runtime Environment"  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_The_sandbox

In python we would use StringIO which is a file like construct in memory.  I have no idea how you might do something similiar in PHP.

Comment: In PHP on AppEngine you can create temporary in-memory files by writing them to php://temp/    For example: file_put_contents("php://temp/my-file", $mydata)

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(test.txt): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /base/data/home/apps/s~emerald-pipe-385/dev.373121059283953780/moreinformation.php on line 4            Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can either export the whole instance [1], or use the mysql command line tool to send the results of a query to a local file [2]

[1] https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/import-export

[2] https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/mysql-client

Comment: I can't export the entire instance as I do a lot of different queries and if I understand that correctly it'd just be a lot of useless data. I tried to see what the commands where for the command line tool but unfortunately the link you gave doesn't have anything useful or else I overlooked it.